# How to enable/visible mat-autocomplete only if condition gets true

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

**UPDATED**

Creating user input popup form, in one field trying to do autocomplete, with [THIS](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbaaqlmqekm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html) solution.

I guess the auto-complete is working fairly fine, the issue is the options not coming below the input box.

Code:

```html
<div>
 <div class="modal-header">
 
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   <form  novalidate [formGroup]="myform">
     <div class="form-floating form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fltName" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <label for="fltName">Name</label>
      

      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #emp="matAutocomplete"  class="form-control">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
         </mat-option>
      <mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
```

**Question:**

**1**. The options box should display, only if there 2 or less matches?

**2**. return emp names options by inserting emp_id?

How can I setup option such as `{name:xyz, emp_id:123, emp_no:333}`, and if I text any value should give name as option like if I write `33` should bring option `xyz`.

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: Hello @yurzui apologies I nubi to angular and dont stackblitz.

Comment: Finally mine is working, I guess the issue was regarding versions, I just run `ng add @angular/material`.

Comment: The question is still open for question 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** The options box should display, only if there 2 or less matches

For this you need to apply the ng-container (To avoid rendering the option box) directive and apply the length condition over there according to your requirement.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <ng-container  *ngIf="filteredOptions && (filteredOptions | async)?.length <= 2">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"   [value]="option" >
      {{option.name}} //this is the value you always want to display
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**Question 2:** return emp names options by inserting emp_id?

The second part can be achieved by applying filter on the required fields, i.e.

```
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  if(value && value !== ""){
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) || option.emp_no.toString().startsWith(filterValue));
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

apart from this you need to fix the pipe part as well, you have to pass the control value in RxJs **startWith** operator like,

```
 this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(this.myControl.value),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );
```

**Note:** you can access the working solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypmnoj?file=src/app/autocomplete-filter-example.ts)

Comment: im in strict mode. i dont understand why (filteredOptions | async)?.length  says Object is possibly 'undefined'. my code is filteredOptions!: Observable<AutoCompleteOption[]>;